# Visual Studio 2012 to 2017 VB Code 'Using .. As..' BC30002 Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I have some VB code originally written in VB using Visual Studio 2012 which I am try to update to Visual Studio 2017 VB. Thus far I've been able to resolve all the conversion errors except one in the statement "Using zip1 As ZipFile = New ZipFile".

The error I receive is "BC30002 Type 'ZipFile' is not defined".

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub DoSave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

        Dim options As WorkerOptions = e.Argument

        Try
            Using zip1 As ZipFile = New ZipFile

                For Each sFile2Backup As String In sFilesToBackup
                    zip1.AddFile(options.Folder & sFile2Backup, "\")
                Next
                For Each sFolder2Backup As String In sFoldersToBackup
                    zip1.AddDirectory(options.Folder & sFolder2Backup, "\" & sFolder2Backup)
                Next

                Me._entriesToZip = zip1.EntryFileNames.Count
                Me.SetProgressBars()
                AddHandler zip1.SaveProgress, New EventHandler(Of SaveProgressEventArgs)(AddressOf Me.zip1_SaveProgress)
                zip1.Save(options.ZipName)

            End Using

        Catch exc1 As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while zipping: {0}", exc1.Message))
            Me.Button_Cancel_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
        End Try

    End Sub     '   **** END Private Sub DoSave()
```

I've tried each of the"Show potential fixes" offered by Visual Studio 2017 but that only increases the number of reported errors.

I'm a "casual" coder, so this one has me really stumped and Dr Google hasn't come forth with viable suggestion so any suggestions/solutions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much nothing that was written in VB 2012 would not be valid in VB 2017.  It's pretty much a given that this and any errors like it are simply the result of not having referenced the appropriate assembly or imported the appropriate namespace.  In that case, you should do what you should ALWAYS do when working with a new type from the Framework: open the documentation for that type and read to see what assembly it is defined in and what namespace it is a member of.  You then add the appropriate reference and/or import to your project and the code you already will work.

Comment: Of course, that assumes that the type is part of the .NET Framework. If it's a third-party type then the same rules apply to using it but you won't find the information in the .NET documentation. You'd need to consult the documentation from the third-party.

Comment: looks like https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip

Comment: You should add a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` in your project and Import `System.IO.Compression` [ZipFile Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @jmcilhinney All my searches of documentation have not revealed an understandable answer for this novice VB/Visual Studio 2017 user.

Comment: @David Sdot - I've read and re-read DotNetZip documentation and I'm afraid that with my limited background in VB programming the solution to my problem is just not evident. I can confirm however that DotNetZip is Referenced in my project.

Comment: As I have said, whatever class that is, you need to reference the assembly it is defined in and import the namespace it's a member of. If you don't know how to do that then that is what you should be researching. With regards to reading documentation, I specifically said that you need to get the assembly and namespace from it, assuming it is a standard .NET class. Is it and, if so, have you? You might benefit from a read of [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html).

Comment: @preciousbetine Both System.IO.Compression.FileSystem and System.IO.Compression are already Referenced in my project, with the latter already included in an Import statement. The  ZipFile Class documentation you've referenced unfortunately only provides a C# example, whereas I'm coding in VB. I've never worked with C#, so do not know the appropriate syntax conversions.

Comment: The .NET `ZipFile` class doesn't have a `SaveProgress` event so it's obviously not that class.  The DotNetZip `ZipFile` class does have such an event, so it is likely that class.  You say that you have referenced DotNetZip.  Have you imported the appropriate namespace.  It's still the same story as three hours ago: determine the class, reference the assembly and import the namespace.

Comment: From the page I linked you can change the language by clicking the </> sign at the top of the page.

Comment: @preciousbetine Thanks for the tip on changing the language in the ZipFile Class documentation. The </> just didn't clue me that it meant language change:-(

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Thanks for the link to your description of Assemblies and Namespaces, it's help clear some confusion but I still haven't been able to work out which Namespace I should be looking for.

Comment: Follow the instructions on that page and you would find what you are looking for.The page also links to pages on how to reference those namespaces.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney By the way John, I found your description very hard to read because of the black background and the dark blue code text.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for all you assistance.  I followed the instructions in your article and as a result I've added the "Ionic.* " group of Namespaces as well as  "System.IO" and "System.IO.Compression". Doing that's just produced an even longer list of errors: " 'Using' operand of type 'ZipFile' must implement 'System.IDisposable'. ", " Overload resolution failed because no 'New' is accessible. " and a bunch of " '????' is not a member of 'ZipFile'." Because of my naivety at VB coding it seems I'm going backwards rather than coming to a resolution.

Comment: *"I found your description very hard to read because of the black background and the dark blue code text"*. Fair point. The site has changed some styles since I posted that. I may have to look at modifying the post to make it more readable.